# Shared Preferences не работает

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Shared Preferences не работает.

сохранение:

```
    private SharedPreferences savesettings;

    String strsettings = "settings1";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        savesettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(settings.this);
            Boolean settings1 = savesettings.getBoolean(strsettings, false);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        if (savesettings.getBoolean(strsettings, false)){
            getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(0xff008577);
        } else {
            getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(BLACK);
        }

        final Switch navbar = findViewById(R.id.navbar);
        navbar.setChecked(settings1);

        navbar.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (navbar.isChecked()){
                    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = savesettings.edit();
                    ed.putBoolean(strsettings, navbar.isChecked());
                    ed.apply();

                    getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(0xff008577);
                } else {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = savesettings.edit();
                    ed.putBoolean(strsettings, navbar.isChecked());
                    ed.apply();

                    getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(BLACK);
                }
            }
        });
```

загрузка:

```
    private SharedPreferences savesettings;

    String strsettings = "settings";

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        savesettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            Boolean settings1 = savesettings.getBoolean(strsettings, false);
        if (savesettings.getBoolean(strsettings, false)){
            getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(0xff008577);
        } else {
            getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(BLACK);
        }
```

Comment: мне лень копаться в вашем несокращенном коде. так что пускай и дальше не работает

Comment: Пожалуйста, прочтите следующее- [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев, сократил код

Comment: другой табак! сейчас посмотрим

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разные переменные

```
String strsettings = "settings1";
```

и

```
String strsettings = "settings";
```

Comment: бинго!!!!!!!!!!!!!!